# VBS Script problems

Tags: vbscript, syntax-error

I asked a question a few days ago about VBS.
I wrote a script that copied files from one folder to another as long as it has the right file extension
This script is coming up with an error saying
"Expected 'Then'"
I'm not sure how to fix this? Whenever I put a "Then" in what I seem to think is the appropriate place, after the if syntax, it still comes up with the same error.

Here's my code, could someone point me in the right direction please?

```
dim filesys

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
objStartFolder = "V:\Auto Audiowall Music Uploads\MUSIC\"

Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(objStartFolder)
Wscript.Echo "Copying only .WAV and .MP3"

Set colFiles = objFolder.Files

For Each objFile in colFiles

If UCase(objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFile.name)) = "MP3" Then
objFSO.CopyFile objFile.Path, "V:\Auto Audiowall Uploads\New Music\"
objFSO.DeleteFile objFile.path
End If
If UCase(objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFile.name)) = "WAV" Then
objFSO.CopyFile objFile.Path, "V:\Auto Audiowall Uploads\New Music\"
objFSO.DeleteFile objFile.path
End If
If Ucase(objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFile.name)) != "MP3" Then
objFSO.DeleteFile objFile.path
End If
If Ucase(objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFile.name)) != "WAV" Then
objFSO.DeleteFile objFile.path
End If

Next

Wscript.echo "Music Copied."
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VBScript does not use `!=` for "not equal". Try replacing `!=` with `<>`.

**Side note:**

Your logic could be simplified to:

```
If MP3 Then
    Copy
ElseIf WAV Then
    Copy
End If

DeleteFile
```

Since you appear to be deleting every file in the end.

Comment: How would you use the <> ? Is it possible to have a greater than or less than in file extensions?

Comment: `<>` doesn't mean "greater than or less than." It means "not equal to". You need to use both characters, together as shown.

Comment: and you can't use them in filenames.

Comment: A `Select` statement would probably be a better choice here: `Select UCase(objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFile.name)) : Case "MP3", "WAV" : objFile.Move "V:\Auto Audiowall Uploads\New Music\" : Case Else : objFile.Delete : End Select`